# limit text in multiple <p> tags in wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, tags

I am working on a blog and wanted to limit the text with "...". but in admin post page it did not allow for 
 tags only P tags separate the paragraph. my point it i want to limit my text even through there are 10 P tags. User can go the page and see the complete post but on landing page it only show a limited text.

please do help.

Comment: There is far too little information here to both understand what you want to do and to formulate a solution.  Please update your question with research and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can use many approaches. One of them is obviously using the_excerpt(); in your template. And if you want to add more characters to that excerpt (other than the default 
ones) try this code in your functions.php file

```
function new_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 50;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');

function the_titlesmall($before = '', $after = '', $echo = true, $length = false) { $title = get_the_title();

    if ( $length && is_numeric($length) ) {
        $title = substr( $title, 0, $length );
    }

    if ( strlen($title)> 0 ) {
        $title = apply_filters('the_titlesmall', $before . $title . $after, $before, $after);
        if ( $echo )
            echo $title;
        else
            return $title;
    }
}
```

Just change `return 50` to any length you want

An alternative: use a content() function in your template, and in your functions.php page use this:

```
function content($limit) {
  $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
  if (count($content)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($content);
    $content = implode(" ",$content).' <a class="seemore" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">More</a>';
  } else {
    $content = implode(" ",$content);
  } 
  $content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
  $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
  return $content;
}
```

And now you can use `<?php echo content(50); ?>` in your template (or replace that 50 with any length you want)

Finally, you can also use the `MORE` tag in your post/page edit screen